# Cloning a repo missing a directory?

Tags: git, blender

I am trying to clone the "Benchmark" branch of the Blender branch so that I can work on running the benchmarking system headlessly. The repo is here:

https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/repository/benchmark/

and per the instructions provided, I've done the following:

```
# read-only access
git clone git://git.blender.org/blender.git

cd blender
git submodule update --init --recursive
git submodule foreach git checkout master
git submodule foreach git pull --rebase origin master
```

However, I find I'm missing the release/scripts/benchmarks directory. Why? How can I "force" getting this directory?

Comment: If their instructions are wrong you may report them a bug.

Comment: I've posted on here as well: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/blender-benchmark-code/9536/3  I am hoping for a response to my edit. This may even be by design, so let's see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the .gitmodules includes:

```
[submodule "release/scripts/benchmark"]
        path = release/scripts/benchmark
        url = ../blender-benchmark-bundle.git
```

Make sure to have cloned the [`blender-benchmark-bundle.git`](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender-benchmark-bundle.git) first, in the sam folder you have cloned `blender.git`.